# hypher.js doesn't work to IE and Chrome

Tags: posts

`functions.php1`

```
wp_register_script( 'en-us', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/en-us.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'en-us');
```

`header.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/bramstein/hypher/master/dist/jquery.hypher.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
      $(function() {
      $('p').hyphenate('en-us');
        });
    });
</script>
```

`.p{color:#fff;  text-align: justify;}`

This only works for Firefox, but not for IE and Chrome. The strange is that when i create simple `index.html` works. What i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What are the console errors?

Comment: i didn't have any console errors.